# handlebars js using collection.first item in different each

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.net

I am trying to use collection firs item property in another each but it does not work,it does not give any error but also it does not work
Bagaj not work but 
Bagaj1 work,altough it is same code,what is problem with this ?

```
    {{#each Flights}}
<tr>
<td>
<div class="col-md-10">
 <strong><span data-i18n="app.booking.flight-number"></span></strong>{{FlightNumber}}
 <strong>Bagaj:</strong>{{PassengerPricing.0.BaggageDescription}}
 </div>
</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
<strong>Bagaj1:</strong>{{PassengerPricing.0.BaggageDescription}}
```

Comment: It is probably due to the context within the `#each` block. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context

Comment: thansk it works